Como usar el efecto AutoAnimate de reveal.js con angular 16?
Tengo un componente en angular llamado "Presentacion1" donde estoy utilizando la libreria reveal.js 5.1.0, el problema es que el "AutoAnimate" no me está funcionando en el navegador, pero si pongo el navegador en vista como dispositivo móvil funciona.
El html está asi:
<div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">
    <section data-auto-animate data-auto-animate-id="one">
        <h2 data-id="title" style="color: red; margin: 50px;">Incidencia con el cliente</h2>          
    </section>
    
    <section data-auto-animate data-auto-animate-id="one">
            <h2 data-id="title" style="color: black;">Incidencia con el cliente</h2>
              <div class="imgCenter"><img style="max-width: 300px;" src="../../../assets/img/incidente.png"></div>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>

Y en en .ts lo inicalizo de esta forma:
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
Reveal.initialize({
  autoAnimate: true,
  controls: true,
  progress: true,
  center: true,
  hash: true,
  embedded: true,
});

